# Entity Reference - show link on referenced node

Tags: entities

I have a "Entity Reference" field in a custom content type. I want to show on any referenced node the link to the node. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution! I just went to "Manage display" of the content type and I checked "Link label to the referenced entity" in the "Entity Reference" field.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a view page. while selecting the entity reference field you have to select the "Formatter:" as Title(link)